# CSS Triangle/Caret Removed when overflow-y applied

Tags: html, css, popover, caret

I have a popover that has a css triangle/caret applied.  The heigh of the popover is dynamic because the output is data driven, and I want it to scroll after 150px height.

When I apply an `overflow-y: scroll`, the caret disappears.

```
.rad {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    color: #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1002;
    padding: 5px 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius:3px;
    max-height: 150px;
    //overflow-y: scroll;
}

.rad:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: -10px;
    content:'';
    width 0;
    height:0;
    border-top:10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #5c5c5c;
}
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/binarygiant/zzLega7g/4/) for the problem.  Uncomment the overflow-y property in the CSS to see the issue.

Desired output:  [image] with scrolling cabability

Comment: It's really because of the scrollbar, can you show us picture resulting you want...

Comment: @C-linkNepal I have updated the question with an image of what I'm actually working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because using `overflow-y: auto` has an unfortunate side-effect of preventing overflow in any direction.  To my knowledge, there is no real way to handle this without applying the `overflow` to a different element.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zzLega7g/9/

In this case, I added `div.content` that will work as an inner wrapper for your content, and will also hold the overflow styles.

Updated CSS:

```
    .rad {
        background-color: #5c5c5c;
        color: #ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 1002;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        border-radius:3px;
    }
    .rad .content {
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 150px;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Move all `.rad` style properties (include `:after`) to its child element, except `position: absolute`. For example, http://jsfiddle.net/zzLega7g/8/ (`.rad` has single child element `div`)

```
.rad {
    position:absolute;
}

.rad > *:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: -10px;
    content:'';
    width 0;
    height:0;
    border-top:10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #5c5c5c;
}

.rad > * {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius:3px;
    overflow-y: scroll;   
    padding: 5px 0;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```